# Tomcat 6 - Java proxy tunneling failed on Windows - ERROR - 407

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy, proxy.pac

I've created a class which deal with HTTP proxy to connect with remote server for web services. Deployed on Tomcat 6, on Windows server 2008 and called in servlet.

1. It is working perfectly with $CATALINA_HOME\bin\tomcat6.exe, i.e. on cmd.
2. It couldn't go through proxy with windows service utility, i.e. $CATALINA_HOME\bin\tomcat6w.exe.

Both are reading same configurations, but behaving differently while establishing connection with remote server through proxy.

I've found few way to get proxy settings, as follows:

1. Proxy Vole utility jar (proxy-vole_20131209.jar).
2. java.net.useSystemProxies set to true and fetch proxy info.
3. Reading PAC with Java code (deploy.jar).
4. Passing constant hostname/IP and port.

All of the above work well with $CATALINA_HOME\bin\tomcat6.exe, other then PAC reading as it fetches private IP instead or public IP (well can ignore for now as long as I know exact hostname and port). 
Note: there is no proxy credentials I've found and it is working without it as well from cmd.
But when I try to run it with tomcat windows service utility, i.e. $CATALINA_HOME\bin\tomcat6w.exe it fails to connect remote server and throws exception: 
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"

Please find my Class, it retry each case one by one all above mentioned (PAC one skipped).

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.ProxySelector;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import com.btr.proxy.search.ProxySearch;
import com.btr.proxy.search.ProxySearch.Strategy;
import com.btr.proxy.util.PlatformUtil;
import com.btr.proxy.util.PlatformUtil.Platform;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.BrowserProxyInfo;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DummyAutoProxyHandler;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.ProxyConfigException;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.ProxyInfo;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.ProxyType;

public class ProxyPacManager {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    getProxy();
}

public static Proxy getProxy(){
    String almProtocol = Constants.getPropereties().getProperty("dashboard.alm.protocol");
    String almHost = Constants.getPropereties().getProperty("dashboard.alm.host");
    String almPort = Constants.getPropereties().getProperty("dashboard.alm.port");
    String urlStr = almProtocol+almHost+":"+almPort;
    Proxy proxy = null;
    List<Proxy> proxyList = null;
    String successMsg = "Proxy not found.";
    try{
        System.out.println("Trying to connect through Proxy Vole plugin.");
        proxyList = getSSLCertificateAutoProxy(urlStr);
        proxy = getProxyTested(proxyList, urlStr);
        successMsg="Successfully connected through Proxy Vole plugin.";
    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Proxy Vole plugin didn't work."+ex.getMessage());
        try{
            System.out.println("Trying to connect through java.net.useSystemProxies Proxy.");
            proxyList = getSSLCertificateSysProxy(urlStr);
            proxy = getProxyTested(proxyList, urlStr);
            successMsg="Successfully connected through java.net.useSystemProxies Proxy.";
        } catch(Exception ex1){
            System.out.println("java.net.useSystemProxies didn't work."+ex1.getMessage());
            try{
                /*System.out.println("Trying to connect through PAC Proxy.");
                proxyList = getSSLCertificatePACProxy(urlStr);
                proxy = getProxyTested(proxyList, urlStr);
                successMsg="Successfully connected through PAC Proxy.";*/
                throw new Exception("Bypass PAC Proxy for testing.");
            }catch(Exception ex2){
                System.out.println("PAC Proxy read didn't work."+ex2.getMessage());
                try{
                    System.out.println("Trying to connect through Constant Proxy.");
                    proxyList = getSSLCertificateConstantProxy();
                    proxy = getProxyTested(proxyList, urlStr);
                    successMsg="Successfully connected through Constant Proxy.";
                }catch(Exception ex3){
                    System.out.println("Constant Proxy read didn't work."+ex3.getMessage());
                    proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
                    proxyList.add(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
                    proxy = getProxyTested(proxyList, urlStr);
                    successMsg = "Connected with NO_PROXY";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(successMsg);
    return proxy;
}

private static Proxy getProxyTested(List<Proxy> proxyList, String urlStr){
    if (proxyList != null && !proxyList.isEmpty()) { 
         for (Proxy proxy : proxyList) { 
             SocketAddress address = proxy.address(); 
             if (address instanceof InetSocketAddress) {
                 System.out.println("Trying to connect through proxy: "+((InetSocketAddress) address).getHostName()+":"+((InetSocketAddress) address).getPort());
                try {
                    URLConnection connection = new URL(urlStr).openConnection(proxy);
                    connection.connect();               
                    System.out.println("Connected through proxy: "+((InetSocketAddress) address).getHostName()+":"+((InetSocketAddress) address).getPort());
                    return proxy; 
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                                  
             } 
         } 
    }
    return null;
}

private static List<Proxy> getSSLCertificateConstantProxy() throws Exception{
    setCertificate();
    List<Proxy> proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
    String proxyHost = Constants.getPropereties().getProperty("dashboard.alm.proxy.host");
    InetAddress hostIp = InetAddress.getByName(proxyHost);
    int proxyPort = Integer.parseInt(Constants.getPropereties().getProperty("dashboard.alm.proxy.port"));

    //Create your proxy and setup authentication for it.
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(hostIp.getHostAddress(), proxyPort));                        
    //Setup authentication for your proxy.
    /*Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

          @Override
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("<user>", "<password>".toCharArray());
          }
    });*/

    proxyList.add(proxy);
    return proxyList; 
}

private static void setCertificate() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, KeyManagementException{
    //First, load the key store file
    String jksFile = Constants.getPropereties().getProperty("dashboard.alm.certificate");
    InputStream trustStream = new FileInputStream(jksFile); 
    String jksPass = Constants.getPropereties().getProperty("dashboard.alm.certificate.pass");
    char[] trustPassword = jksPass.toCharArray();

    //Initialize a KeyStore
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(trustStream, trustPassword);

    //Initialize TrustManager objects.
    TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustFactory.init(trustStore);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();

    //Create a new SSLContext, load the TrustManager objects into it and set it as default.
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);
    SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);  
}
private static ProxyInfo[] getProxyInfo(String urlStr) throws ProxyConfigException, MalformedURLException{      
    String proxypac = Constants.getPropereties().getProperty("dashboard.alm.proxy.pac");        
    BrowserProxyInfo b = new BrowserProxyInfo();
    /*WDefaultBrowserProxyConfig wd = new WDefaultBrowserProxyConfig();
    BrowserProxyInfo b = wd.getBrowserProxyInfo();        */
    b.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
    b.setAutoConfigURL(proxypac);       
    DummyAutoProxyHandler handler = new DummyAutoProxyHandler();
    handler.init(b);

    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(url);     

    return ps;
}

public static List<Proxy> getSSLCertificateAutoProxy(String urlStr) throws Exception{           
    setCertificate();
    /*ProxySearch proxySearch = ProxySearch.getDefaultProxySearch();*/
    ProxySearch proxySearch = new ProxySearch();
    proxySearch.setPacCacheSettings(32, 1000*60*5);
    if (PlatformUtil.getCurrentPlattform() == Platform.WIN) { 
        proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.IE); 
        proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.FIREFOX); 
        proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.JAVA); 
    } else if (PlatformUtil.getCurrentPlattform() == Platform.LINUX) { 
        proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.GNOME); 
        proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.KDE); 
        proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.FIREFOX); 
    } else { 
        proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.OS_DEFAULT); 
    }       


    ProxySelector proxySelector = proxySearch.getProxySelector();
    /*BufferedProxySelector cachedSelector = new BufferedProxySelector(32, 1000*60*5, proxySelector);*/


    ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector); 
    //ProxySelector.setDefault(cachedSelector);
    URI home = URI.create(urlStr);  
    //List<Proxy> proxyList = cachedSelector.select(home); 
    List<Proxy> proxyList = proxySelector.select(home);
    return proxyList;
}

public static List<Proxy> getSSLCertificatePACProxy(String urlStr) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, KeyManagementException, ProxyConfigException{
    List<Proxy> proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
    setCertificate();       
    ProxyInfo[] ps = getProxyInfo(urlStr);      
    for(ProxyInfo p: ps){

        String proxyHost = p.getProxy();
        int proxyPort = p.getPort(); 

        //Create your proxy and setup authentication for it.
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));                      
        //Setup authentication for your proxy.
        /*Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

              @Override
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("<user>", "<password>".toCharArray());
              }
        });*/
        proxyList.add(proxy);

    }
    return proxyList;

}


public static List<Proxy> getSSLCertificateSysProxy(String urlStr) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, KeyManagementException, ProxyConfigException, URISyntaxException{
    setCertificate();       
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true");
    List<Proxy> proxyList = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI(urlStr));

    return proxyList;

}

}
```

Failure output of the class,

```
Trying to connect through java.net.useSystemProxies Proxy.
java.net.useSystemProxies didn't work.null
PAC Proxy read didn't work.Bypass PAC Proxy for testing.
Trying to connect through Constant Proxy.
Trying to connect through proxy: XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080 [Masked for security reasons]
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
```

Please help me to get through the proxy with Tomcat 6 windows service utility.
Note: Windows security policy:
Network security: LAN Manager authentication level = Send NTLM response only

Answer (score 0):

Please if someone have any solution for the issue let me know, ASAP.
I'll break the code for more understanding:

1. Get proxy by Proxy vole plugin/jar

   ```
    public static List<Proxy> getSSLCertificateAutoProxy(String urlStr) throws Exception{          
   setCertificate();
   /*ProxySearch proxySearch = ProxySearch.getDefaultProxySearch();*/
   ProxySearch proxySearch = new ProxySearch();
   proxySearch.setPacCacheSettings(32, 1000*60*5);
   if (PlatformUtil.getCurrentPlattform() == Platform.WIN) { 
       proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.IE); 
       proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.FIREFOX); 
       proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.JAVA); 
   } else if (PlatformUtil.getCurrentPlattform() == Platform.LINUX) { 
       proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.GNOME); 
       proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.KDE); 
       proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.FIREFOX); 
   } else { 
       proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.OS_DEFAULT); 
   }       


   ProxySelector proxySelector = proxySearch.getProxySelector();
   /*BufferedProxySelector cachedSelector = new BufferedProxySelector(32, 1000*60*5, proxySelector);*/


   ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector); 
   //ProxySelector.setDefault(cachedSelector);
   URI home = URI.create(urlStr);  
   //List<Proxy> proxyList = cachedSelector.select(home); 
   List<Proxy> proxyList = proxySelector.select(home);
   return proxyList;
   }
   ```
2. Get Proxy using java.net.useSystemProxies

   ```
   public static List<Proxy> getSSLCertificateSysProxy(String urlStr) throws Exception{
    setCertificate();      
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true");
    List<Proxy> proxyList = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI(urlStr));

    return proxyList;

   }
   ```
3. Get proxy from PAC:

   ```
   public static List<Proxy> getSSLCertificatePACProxy(String urlStr) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, KeyManagementException, ProxyConfigException{
   setCertificate();       
   List<Proxy> proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
   String proxypac = "<http://mydomain/proxy.pac>";        
   BrowserProxyInfo b = new BrowserProxyInfo();
   /*WDefaultBrowserProxyConfig wd = new WDefaultBrowserProxyConfig();
   BrowserProxyInfo b = wd.getBrowserProxyInfo();        */
   b.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
   b.setAutoConfigURL(proxypac);       
   DummyAutoProxyHandler handler = new DummyAutoProxyHandler();
   handler.init(b);

   URL url = new URL(urlStr);
   ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(url); 
   for(ProxyInfo p: ps){

       String proxyHost = p.getProxy();
       int proxyPort = p.getPort(); 

       //Create your proxy and setup authentication for it.
       Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));                      
       //Setup authentication for your proxy.
       /*Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

             @Override
             protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new PasswordAuthentication("<user>", "<password>".toCharArray());
             }
       });*/
       proxyList.add(proxy);

   }
   return proxyList;

   }
   ```
4. Get proxy by directly passing known proxy hostname and port

   ```
   private static List<Proxy> getSSLCertificateConstantProxy() throws Exception{

    setCertificate();
    List<Proxy> proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
    String proxyHost = "<myproxy.hostname>";
    InetAddress hostIp = InetAddress.getByName(proxyHost);
    int proxyPort = Integer.parseInt("<myProxyPort>"));

    //Create your proxy and setup authentication for it.
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(hostIp.getHostAddress(), proxyPort));                       
    //Setup authentication for your proxy.
    /*Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

         @Override
         protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           return new PasswordAuthentication("<user>", "<password>".toCharArray());
         }
    });*/

    proxyList.add(proxy);
    return proxyList; 
   }
   ```